# How to use the WebSpeech API in svelte

Tags: svelte, vite, webspeech-api

I am working on a frontend project which involves the use of the google WebSpeech API. When I try to declare the speech recognition, I get errors saying speech recognition is not defined or window is not defined. The project fails to compile. How do I fix this?

The code inside my  tag is below;

```
const SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
```

This is the error

window is not defined
ReferenceError: window is not defined

I am using vite-plugin-svelte for compiling & Chrome browser for testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `window` object doesn't exist on the server, so you need to make sure it is only used in the browser.

You could e.g. initialize `recognition` in the browser only with [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-onmount).

**Example**

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';

  let recognition;

  onMount(() => {
    const SpeechRecognition = window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
    recognition = new SpeechRecognition();
  });
</script>
```